# プリンタ選択ダイアログを表示しないでプリント枚数とプリントサイズを指定して印刷実行

Tags: c#

プリンタ選択ダイアログを表示させて印刷するプログラムは作成済ですが、マニュアル操作では時間が掛かってしまうので、印刷ボタンを押すだけでプリンタやプリントサイズ、枚数を指定して印刷実行させる方法を教えていただきたいです。よろしくお願い致します。

環境
Windows 10 Pro
Visual Studio Commnunity 2015 C#

Comment: pgrho様　早々の回答ありがとうございました。

Answer (score 1):

Windows Formの`System.Drawing.Printing`名前空間を使用している場合は`PrintDocument`の`PrintSettings`を事前に設定しておけばよいです。

```
// PrintDocument d;
d.PrintSettings.PrinterName = "プリンター名";
d.PrintSettings.Copies = 部数;
d.DefaultPageSettings.PaperSize = サイズ;

d.Print();
```